# Using LIMIT WHERE at once in SELECT SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

I've got problem with SELECT SQL since ive included LIMIT, so my code looks like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE rl_threads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$id'";

$sql = mysql_query($sql);

//Pager

$ile = 10;

if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
  $strona = $_GET['page'];
}
else
{
  $strona = 1;
}

$strona = $strona - 1;

$offset = $strona * $ile;

//Koniec Pagera

$sql = "SELECT * FROM rl_posts LIMIT $od, 10 WHERE thread_id = '$id'";

$sql = mysql_query($sql);
```

until i havent add limit it worked properly but after the script says:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/radiolev/public_html/forum.php on line 194
Partnerzy
```

Can someone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: I see no mysql_fetch_array() in your code, I guess is right after $sql = mysql_query($sql). Probably the query failed (and $sql is FALSE), put the "LIMIT $od, 10" after the WHERE clause

Comment: it worked before limit and if i delete limit from code it works so its not a problem

Comment: what this $od ? how its defined ?

Comment: If you read my comment, I say to use LIMIT _after_ the WHERE. `WHERE thread_id = $id LIMIT $od,10`. And sanitize your inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The correct `SELECT` syntax has `LIMIT` *after* the `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rl_posts WHERE thread_id = '$id' LIMIT $od, 10";
```

The error you're receiving, `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`... is caused when the MySQL query fails. Updating to the above should fix the issue, assuming you have `$od` defined somewhere (if it's not defined, you will get see the same warning).

Side-note, not answer specific:
I would recommend upgrading to the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extensions. Both support prepared statements which can make your queries easier to read/manage and also offer additional security against SQL-Injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM rl_posts WHERE thread_id = '$id' LIMIT $od, 10
```